# System.out.println error New programmer

Tags: java, eclipse, output, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to do a simple input program and I get an error on the `System.out.println` command, I don't know why it doesn't accept the command and can't continue working until I fix it.

The error says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
```

My code goes as follows.

```
package classPack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numone = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("please input the number of numbers you want to analyze");
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numtwo = s.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Not inside a method... wrap all that in `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`

Comment: forgot to do that, stupid me, quick additional question, now on the scanner s and r lines it says: Resource leak: 's' is never 
 closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        // you only need one instance of scanner
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numone = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please input the number of numbers you want to analyze");
        int numtwo = s.nextInt();
        // don't forget to close the scanner
        s.close();    
    }
}
```

In Java, you must put code inside *methods*, not at the class level. In particular, you can put it inside the `main()` method, which is the entry point for the execution of all programs.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing something.....but you can try this "user input" code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {     
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int numone = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("please input the number of numbers you want to analyze");
Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
int numtwo = s.nextInt();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Multi {
  public static void doSomething() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numone = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("please input the number of numbers you want to analyze");
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numtwo = s.nextInt();
    }
  }
}

public class MultiplicationTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Multi.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Animal {

    public String name;
    public static int nosLegs;



    public Animal(){

    }

    public Animal(String name, int nosLegs) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.nosLegs = nosLegs;
    }


    //getter and setter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getNosLegs() {
        return nosLegs;
    }
    public void setNosLegs(int nosLegs) {
        this.nosLegs = nosLegs;
    }


    public class B{


        public int b;

        System.out.println("hello");

    }



}
change in Main method...
```